# Function Visibility specifiers during inheritance

Tags: solidity, contract-design, 0x, inheritance, visibility

when am overriding a function in solidity must my child function have the same visibility as the parent function? can the parent function be public and the child function be internal

Comment: nope, it should be same

Comment: Thank you very much